# Evaluating a sum in SymPy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sympy

I want to evaluate the sum

[image]

using Python and SymPy, I'm relatively new using SymPy and the first thing I tried was

```
from sympy import exp, oo, summation, symbols

n, x = symbols('n,x')
summation(exp(-n*x), (n, 1, oo))
```

But it doesn't work, it just returns the unevaluated sum.
I can make it work using

```
from sympy import exp, oo, summation, symbols

n, x = symbols('n,x')
f = exp(-x)
summation(x**(-n), (n, 1, oo)).subs(x,f)
```

But I would like to know if it is possible to make it work without need to break the expression into x^n and then substitute x by e^-x.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
x , n = smp.symbols('x n')
smp.Sum(smp.exp(-n*x),(n, 1, smp.oo))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Hi, is this working for you? In my case with Python 3.9.7 and SymPy 1.9, this doesn't work. Also looking at the documentation for smp.Sum we have "Represents unevaluated summation." which is not what I want.